# CTRL+SHIFT+??? also changes language, when just CTRL+SHIFT should do it

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

Just moved from Unity to **GNOME** and faced such problem:
I change keyboard layouts by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Often use console and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> (or any other combinations, where there are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>), GNOME also changes keyboard layout language.

In Unity, and in Windows, the computer normally waits whether I add to the combination any additional keys or release at least one of the keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>) in order to change the language. GNOME, in my case, changes the language immediately once <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> are pressed.

I have Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, x64 (Fresh installation, downloaded from https://ubuntugnome.org)

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: @pomsky, actually the thread you linked is a duplication, because my question was made earlier :), but overall I agree, it is duplication.

Comment: You're very right about the time of posting of both questions, but [in Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18173) and in the [whole of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643) in general it is acceptable to mark an older question as duplicate of a newer one. I noticed your question is older, but I chose to vote in the other direction as I observed the answers posted to the other one are relatively more detailed. Your question would still work as a great signpost to the other :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known ugly bug - see [launchpad bug 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1245473).

I'm writing this from Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with MATE DE. It does not have this problem.
I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> layout switcher for English and Russian languages.
I see no interference here.

But MATE on Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 LTS has this problem - see other [launchpad bug 1720364](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1720364).

My complete position is written [in comment 528 for bug 1218322 at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322/comments/528).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you may set another key combination instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch keyboard layouts which is not used in console.
For example you may try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>.

Comment: ... or <Super> + <Space>, which is the default shortcut for changing input source.