# Ubuntu ctrl+shift is set to 19.10 to unset

Tags: keyboard, input-language, input-method

I use Ubuntu 19.10 the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> is somehow set to change the input method. Actually both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> switch the layout.

I found this:

[CTRL+SHIFT+??? also changes language, when just CTRL+SHIFT should do it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784864/ctrlshift-also-changes-language-when-just-ctrlshift-should-do-it).

But I refuse to believe it is dead end.

Because of that all other combination that involve <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Something</kbd> - that I used to - does not work for me, instead it change the input method and makes matter worst.

When look up for the settings: in "keyboard shortcuts" I set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

**Question is:** What is the possible solution to unset it, other than reinstalling the whole system or switching to MS Windows :)

Comment: Also, since it happened at upgrade, what's the output of this command: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: @PRATAP exactly that: ['grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']

Comment: yeaaah! :) Alright will stay with gnome :)

Comment: would be better if i could find it on ui. and actually while upgrading, ubutu asked me for that combination in text only manner. I wondered why it asks that specif question about layout. happy that it works now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input switch in ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189949/input-switch-in-ubuntu-19-10)