# How to remove a keyboard combination on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I recently updated to Ubuntu 19.10 and it asked me to set up a key for changing languages recommending me Ctl. + Alt. I accepted without thinking Alt. + Ctl + L is my reformat combo in Intelij and Alt + Ctr + T is my terminal combo.
 The old language switch combo (Super + Shift) is still active and I much prefer it. Can I delete the new one?

Comment: a similar Q is recently asked. https://askubuntu.com/q/1187001/739431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the standard shortcuts:
Go to **Settings > Devices > Keyboard**
Scroll down to "**Typing**"
Change the current set shortcut into something else.

EDIT:
To disable CTRL+ALT (or similar shortcuts for changing language) do the following:

1. Install the GNOME Tweak Tool
   `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
   and open it:
   `gnome-tweaks`
2. Then go to **Keyboard & Mouse** and click the button "**Addtional Layout Options**"
3. Look for "**Switching to another layout**" and click on it.

There you can unselect CTRL+ALT.

Comment: I already tried that. It shows only the old shortcut

Answer (score 0):

In the Dashboard go to Text Entry and try setting the shortcut there.