# Input switch in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've updated my Ubuntu to 19.10 couple of weeks ago and on installation system suggests to change or add shortcut for input source selection despite one was already defined previously. I've added <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> shortcut and just realized that it somehow overlapped any other <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>something</kbd> shortcuts globally, i.e. when I want to open new window in vscode, it opens new tab and it looks like system doesn't see the <kbd>shift</kbd> button press.

I tried to search this combination in shortcuts settings, but it's just not there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check if there is a shortcut for input-switch assigned with `xkb-options` other than those assigned under system-settings -- >> keyboard -- >> keyboard shortcuts, using below command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Example output: `['grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']`

check the meanings of the options you got from above output with this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html)

then use gsettings set command to remove the required option. for example

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['grp_led:scroll']"
```

Alternatively you can use `gnome-tweaks` (`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`) like below.

[image: Hi]