# Caps lock now used to switch languages (I can't get rid of it)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

After an update, now the caps lock is also used to switch language keyboard (rather than Super key+space) which is super annoying. I have not found a way to disable it in the keyboard shortcuts. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1189949/739431

Answer (score 0):

go to control panel- language and region- change input methods- advanced settings- change language bar hot keys

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem such as this for a long time, and the GNOME settings didn't work. If you're still stuck, try

```
setxkbmap us
```

Provided that works, but it's not persistent between sessions, try putting it in `~/.bashrc` or something.

As per [Permanently set keyboard layout options with setxkbmap in gnome/unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity), GNOME may be resetting the keyboard map. In that case,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

would have to be used. You may also look to that page for a less temporary setup if `setxkbmap us` does work.

Sorry about getting to you so late; I've been wanting to answer this question for months, but it has only been recently that I have both known the answer, could find this question on Google, and have had a desire to answer it.

As such time has passed since I came up with my solution in Gnome, I have moved on from Gnome, so I have unfortunately been unable to verify that my memory regarding my solution is correct.